# Staggered Grid View unable to show data in 2 columns

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, flutter-widget, staggered-gridview

**I am very new at Dart so if this problem seems trivial or not required, I apologize!!**

I want to implement Pinterest-style grid layout for my feed with only 2 columns. I am using the [staggered_grid_layout](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) and I tried implementing an answer from a stackoverflow question. Here is my code till now:

**home.dart**

```
SizedBox(
            height: 535,
            width: 180,
            child: new StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Card(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.network(storiesList[index]),
                    Text("Some text"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
              new StaggeredTile.fit(2),
              mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
              crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
            ),
          )
```

[link to full code](https://gist.github.com/shlokjain2031/0dce3e2e4def54bdb995f54b49b68882)

**NOTE:** I added the `SizedBox()` because I was getting a `Vertical viewport was given unbounded height` error, please recommend an alternative if that is not alright

Thank you!

**EDIT:** How it looks right now

[image: How it looks right now]

**EDIT:** How it should look

[image: How it should look]

Comment: Your question is not clear! Can you show us what do you exactly want.

Comment: updated my question, please look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for update, Check out below code no need of StaggeredGridView instead use GridTile,

```
GridView.count(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 1.0,              
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          children: new List<Widget>.generate(3, (index) {
            return new GridTile(
              child: InkResponse(
                child: new Card(
                // color:Colors.white,
                child: new Center(
                  child: new Text('XYZ'),
                 ),
                ),
                enableFeedback: true,
                onTap: () => _onSelected(index, items[index].toString().substring(0,10)), // Whatever you want on tap
                ),
              );
          }),
        ),
```

Comment: yeah but this would make them stay in a fixed width and height, but I want the height of one item to scale as per the image it hosts

Comment: Use MediaQuery for height and width this will increase and decrease as per your screen height and width See below code :: height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5

Answer (score 0):

`CrossAxisCount` is the number of "tiles" you want to divide the grid. `StaggeredTile.fit(x)` is the number of tiles you want to use for `item[index]`. So, if `CrossAxisCount` is 2, `StaggeredTile` should be fit(1), if you want 2 columns. You can even say `CrossAxisCount` is 8 and `StaggeredTile.fit(4)` for 2 columns, `StaggeredTile.fit(2)` for 4 columns... and so on. In this way you can change Columns number for each row depending on any condition placed for `StaggeredTile.fit`.